# MySQL return Null = 0 on joined table with filter on one table

Tags: mysql, join, null

I'm trying to return a result which gives me a total transaction value for every day in a period. I have 2 tables, 'calendar' which has all days between 2013-12-31 and 2014-12-31. And a second table that stores all 'customer_transactions'. I'd like my result to look something like:

```
DATE         |      sum(value)
...                   ...
2014-07-28            10
2014-07-27            7
2014-07-26            0
2014-07-25            0
2014-07-24            5
...                   ...
```

I have built a query that works:

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE,
       IFNULL(SUM(ct.value),0) AS total_sales
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN customer_transactions as ct ON (calendar.datefield = from_unixtime(ct.date_edit, '%Y-%m-%d'))
WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2013-12-31') AND ('2014-12-31'))
GROUP BY DATE
```

However I want to filter my results to return only the transactions for a certain customer based on a column in the customer_transactions table (e.g. customer_id=5)

If I add a WHERE clause as follows:

```
    SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE,
               IFNULL(SUM(ct.value),0) AS total_sales
    FROM calendar
    LEFT JOIN customer_transactions as ct ON (calendar.datefield = from_unixtime(ct.date_edit, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2013-12-01') AND ('2014-07-28'))
    AND ct.customer_id=5
    GROUP BY DATE
```

My null=0 values are no longer shown. I have searched high and low but cannot find what I'm doing wrong, I assume it's some sort of logic issue to do with the JOIN.

Note: dates stored in 'customer_transactions' table are Unix Timestamps and as 2014-01-01 format in 'calendar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the condition to the wrong part of the query.

`LEFT JOIN` nulls all the columns of the `customer_transactions` for `calendar` records without a transaction. Adding `ct.customer_id=5` to the `WHERE` removes all these nulled value rows as `ct.customer_id` is `NULL`.

You want to add the condition to the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
   SELECT calendar.datefield AS date, IFNULL(SUM(ct.value),0) AS total_sales
     FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN customer_transactions as ct 
       ON (calendar.datefield = from_unixtime(ct.date_edit, '%Y-%m-%d'))
      AND ct.customer_id=5
    WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2013-12-31') AND ('2014-12-31'))
 GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Simple and clean.